# Get counter of product units of several orders

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

After a lot of trying I got a query that returns all the products and units of each product of all the orders of a day.

Is this:

```
SELECT
    it.order_id as pedido,
    it.order_item_name as nombre,
    it.order_item_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN itm.meta_key = '_product_id' THEN itm.meta_value END) as producto,
    MAX(CASE WHEN itm.meta_key = '_qty' THEN itm.meta_value END) as qt,
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_weight' and post_id = 
    MAX(CASE WHEN itm.meta_key = '_product_id' THEN itm.meta_value END)
    ) as peso,
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta where meta_key = 'entrega' and post_id = 
    p.ID
    ) as fecha
FROM wp_posts as p
    inner join wp_woocommerce_order_items as it
        on it.order_id = p.ID
    inner join wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as itm
        on itm.order_item_id = it.order_item_id
    inner join wp_postmeta as pm
        on pm.post_id = p.ID
WHERE order_item_type = 'line_item' 
    and it.order_item_id = itm.order_item_id
    and itm.meta_key = '_qty' or itm.meta_key = '_product_id'
GROUP BY order_item_id
```

It works perfectly, but now I want it to do only for orders with status: "Processing"

I add this in the Where:

```
and p.post_status = 'wc-processing'
```

And nothing happens.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid mixing ands and ors, use brackets to enforce the precedence of the conditions you want so probably-

```
WHERE order_item_type = 'line_item' 
    and it.order_item_id = itm.order_item_id
    and (itm.meta_key = '_qty' or itm.meta_key = '_product_id')
    and p.post_status = 'wc-processing'
```

Comment: Really simple. Thank you!